# Is TIG or laser welding feasable for building aluminum habitats either on the Moon or in orbit?

Tags: the-moon, construction, habitat, reduced-gravity-manufacturing

The question was originally spurred by Andy Weir's *Artemis* - in the novel oxyacetylene and neon are extensively used for cutting and welding. TIG or laser welding seem like the obvious choices for their relative safety and precision, but I don't know what material thickness they would be capable of on large thermally-conductive structures in vacuum.

[Have things been intentionally welded in space? If so, what kinds of metals and techniques were used, and why was it necessary?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/52091/12102) mentions experiments with electron beam cutting and welding, but the Wikipedia page seems to indicate it has limited penetration (on the order of 0.01 mm) and produces very thin weld lines.

Comment: (Partially) Relevant paper: https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20200002259/downloads/20200002259.pdf

Comment: TIG stands for Tungsten Inert Gas, where the gas' purpose is to shield the weld from oxygen in the atmosphere to prevent oxidation while it cools.  Obviously just shielding wouldn't be needed in a vacuum.  So any vacuum welding process likely won't look anything like the processes used inside our atmosphere.   I would imagine the biggest hurdle would be dissipating the heat, as all processes on Earth rely on the atmosphere to do that.  Which is probably why you're just finding small scale tests.  The issue isn't penetration depth, but preventing the entire part from melting.

Comment: @GregMiller ... the inert gas in MIG and TIG is also used to cool the weld. Different mixes of Ar, CO2 and He are used. Welding in space may still need "shielding gas" for cooling. But I suspect that for long welds of uniform thickness material, control of arc current could balance heat loss by conduction.

Comment: Interesting!!  I find myself wondering about initiating and then sustaining an arc.  And whatever shielding gas you used, it would be at a vastly lower pressure and density than under atmospheric pressure.  And similar thoughts for oxyfuel.. the absolute pressure/density would be vastly lower, how would the flame look/work at a tenth or a twentieth of the density?

Comment: Related and potentially helpful: [Power requirements for NASA's Variable Power Laser Welding Torch](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25621/12102)

Comment: @Woody while every weld is different, in the vastly overwhelming majority of cases the heat is mostly disapated through the rest of the part and into the atmosphere.  While you could theoretically turn up the flow rate enough to provide enough cooling, it would likely distort or blow away the weld.  The cooling would be better applied somewhere else on the part.  Such cases come up often in practice and require clamping the part to a heat sink (often the welding table itself) as the gas certainly does not provide sufficient cooling.

Comment: @GregMiller ... you are correct. The majority of the bulk heat is conducted away by the base metal. However, the temperature at the puddle is affected by the gasses present. Helium conducts much faster than Argon, resulting in shallower, broader beads. That is why Ar/He mixes are chosen for the specific job.  https://www.thefabricator.com/thefabricator/article/consumables/whats-up-with-helium-for-welding-applicationsr#:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer: I think wire-feed MIG (metal inert gas) welding would be the better choice for structural aluminum space habitats. https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19940000578

TIG (tungsten inert gas) has advantages for tricky-to-weld materials https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19970019597 particularly thin materials.

Welding obviously requires heat by way of an arc (TIG), laser, electrical resistance (spot weld) etc. But structural welding (like a habitat) also needs filler material to fill inevitable gaps in the weld line. If filler is not supplied, the weld line is thinner (weaker) than the surrounding base metal.

Habitat structures are reasonably thick. The ISS hull is double-walled 4mm aluminum. Compare that with a shipping container's 2mm steel walls.

TIG and laser are both torches: they supply heat but not filler. For constructing structures, they need filler as well, like a stick or motorized wire feed.

MIG welding uses a motorized wire feed electrode which supplies filler and continuously renews the electrode. In addition, the wire can be flux-cored to add chemical components to the arc and weld line.

The inert gas (the "I" in MIG) protects the puddle from oxidation when welding in the atmosphere. This is obviously not needed in a vacuum. But the inert gas also supports the arc in a vacuum. Gas flow also removes heat which will be an issue in space.

Manual welding of aluminum is tricky since aluminum does not glow before it melts, unlike steel. The astronaut/welder would likely benefit from automated control of inert gas flow and current to limit puddle temperature.

Weld quality assurance would be problematic for lunar job site welding. Robotic welding using 3D printing technology could potentially optimize consistency. https://www.relativityspace.com

Comment: this all sounds perfectly reasonable, but citations would be helpful

Comment: agreed; quality, reliable aluminum welding requires both special equipment and skill & experience. It's hard to find good aluminum space welders these days! It may be a bit easier in vacuum, the IG part of TIG might not be necessary?

Comment: @uhoh ... Yes. The learning curve would be a problem. You could give me a Stradivarius, but it wouldn't make me a violinist.

Comment: Will the arc work in a vaccuum / in rapidly expanding argon? You might get more of a glow discharge.

Comment: @ikrase oh, maybe I am totally stupid here. I assumed the function of the inert gas was to prevent rapid oxidation (burning) of hot bare aluminum in an oxygen atmosphere. Yes of course you are right, a continuous, conventional high energy arc needs an electrically conductive plasma to flow through. It doesn't have to be exactly 1 atmosphere, but if you spray gas in a vacuum ambient it will be really hard to maintain a relatively constant pressure and therefore a relatively constant heating. *I guess then* that an inert gas and a stabilized ambient pressure may both be needed for arc welding.

Comment: @ikrase and perhaps this is why NASA is looking at a [Variable Power Laser Welding Torch](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25621/12102)

Comment: @uhoh ... vacuum welding of aluminum has been investigated by NASA using inert gas delivered through a hollow tungsten electrode. "The tensile strength of the square butt joint ... in a vacuum is nearly equal to that of the same joint welded by conventional <inert gas>  ... welding in air"

Comment: @Woody clever folks those NASA engineers and their vacuum chambers ;-)

Comment: @Woody is the quote about the strength of the butt joints from one of the citations in the answer? I didn't find it on a quick skim